# OpenGL profiling with AMD PerfStudio 2

Tags: opengl, performance, profiling

I'm rendering just a really small amount of polygons for my UI but however I still tried to increase the FPS. In the end I removed redundant calls which increased the FPS. I really don't want to lose FPS for nothing so I keep looking for more improvements.

[image: APITrace from AMD PerfStudio2]

The first thing I noticed is the "huge" time where no calls are made before SwapBuffer (the black one). Well I know that OpenGL works asynchronous so SwapBuffer has to wait until everything is done. But shouldn't *PerfStudio* mark this time also as black ? Correct me If I am wrong.

The second thing I noticed is that some `glUniform2f` calls just take longer (the brown ones). I mean they should all upload `2floats` to the GPU how can the time be so different from call to call. The program isn't even changed or something like that.

I also tried to look at other programs like [gDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) or [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/) but they often crashed and they show less statistics (only # of calls or redundant calls etc.)

**EDIT**: I also realized that the draw calls also have different durations, which was obvious for me but sometimes drawing more vertices is faster than drawing less vertices.

Comment: Are you batching or doing separate draw calls for each of your quads?

Comment: You don't have a particularly clear question here.  The times of things will vary a lot; there's a _lot_ going on under the hood between driver state caches, OS context switches, various hardware queues, etc.  Was that your question?